# Passing Variables via Query String (php)

Tags: php, arrays, variables

I'm slowly learning PHP through an online course. A particular exercise goes like so:

the html page:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Greeting the Beatles</title>
</head>
<body>
    Choose a Beatle to greet.
    <ul>
    <li><a href="HelloWho.php?Beatle=Paul">Paul</a></li>
    <li><a href="HelloWho.php?Beatle=John">John</a></li>
    <li><a href="HelloWho.php?Beatle=George">George</a></li>
    <li><a href="HelloWho.php?Beatle=Ringo">Ringo</a></li>
    </ul>
</body>
</html>
```

the corresponding php page:

```
<?php
$beatle = $_GET['Beatle'];
?>
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Hello <?php echo $beatle ?>!</title>
</head>
<body>
<?php
    echo "Hello $beatle!";
?>
</body>
</html>
```

My code is identical to the above and yet I keep getting a page saying I have an undefined index on line 2:

```
Notice: Undefined index: Greet in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/Webucator/ClassFiles/Webucator/ClassFiles/PHPBasics/Exercises/HelloWho.php on line 2
World!
```

I realize this is a dumb question, but I haven't seen an answer for it yet, aside from the isset() function which, I haven't learned about yet.

Comment: Not sure I see that error message jiving with what you pasted for code.  Sure nothing was changed?  Checking existence with `isset` is definitely how that type of notice is handled.

Comment: Are you sure the code is exactly the one you've pasted in? The error message says otherwise

Comment: Probably you are accessing the wrong file...

Comment: Can't see why that wouldn't work. Paste your code.

Comment: Code is ok. It has to be other file. In you code you have `Beatle` but in error there is `Greet` Undefined index

Comment: As you say `My code is identical` so post it, so we can see the real problem.

Comment: There's no extra files included?  The error means that you're trying to do this: `$array['Greet'];` when `$array` doesn't have an index for `Greet`... so your situation is that `isset($array['Greet'])===false`... only the code you've posted doesn't mention anything with `Greet` and the closest shown is `$_GET['Beatle'];`

Comment: Show us the file : Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/Webucator/ClassFiles/Webucator/ClassFiles/PHPBasics/Exercises/HelloWho.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code you posted does work properly, and does not give the error that you posted.

Reading what the error says can easily fix your problem. It says there is an undefined index "Greet" on line 2.

Ensure that in your copy you have the same line 2 as the working version

```
$beatle = $_GET['Beatle'];
```

If you look closer at how this works, you see the url that you are passing data to is

```
HelloWho.php?Beatle=NameGoesHere
```

The PhP file is able to get the data from

```
?Beatle=
```

By using

```
$_GET['Beatle']
```

and storing it in a variable like it has in line two

```
$beatle = $_GET['Beatle'];
```

Moreover, I know you said you have yet to learn it, but you can use isset() to check if the string exists

```
if (isset($_GET['Beatle'])) {
    $beatle = $_GET['Beatle'];
    echo "Hello $beatle!";
}
```