# Passing PHP Variable that is not from FORM To Another PHP page

Tags: php, variables

I want to pass a variable from PHP to another PHP page. I've seen a lot of solutions but they only pass variables that is obtained from a specific form. I just want to pass a simple variable like these $var = 12;. Thanks!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Passing Variables via Query String (php)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19868038/passing-variables-via-query-string-php)

Answer (score 0):

You can either pass it as a get parameter like this: 
`example.com/page.php?var=YOURVARIABLE`
and then get it like this `$_GET["var"]`.

You can also use a form as mentioned:

`<input type="text" value="<?php $var?>">`

and get it through form.

Answer (score -1):

As an alternative to what David proposes, you can look into the `$_SESSION` variable. See also [this page](https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_sessions.asp) from W3Schools.

-- a.php --

```
session_start();
$_SESSION['variable'] = 12;
```

-- b.php --

```
session_start();
echo $_SESSION['variable'];
// Will return 12
```